# Multiple Intents on Main Menu

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, menu

Good afternoon,

I am a new user to Android eclipse.I have created a Menu with 3 buttons which will lead the user onto 3 seperate pages given their choice, each given their own intent however I am getting many errors in my code and am wondering am I doing it the correct way and if not which way should I approach this simple main menu

UPDATE: There now appears to be no errors in running the code however the buttons remain unresponsive

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.techblogon.loginexample.MainMenu" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/PIC" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnWorkout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnhealth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Log/View Workout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnhealth"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Health Tips" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnhealth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnhealth"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Logout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Class:

```
package com.techblogon.loginexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;





public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    private Context context;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle setInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(setInstanceState);
        context=this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        return true;
    }

    public boolean btnhealth(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Tips.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;

    }
    public boolean btnWorkout(View view){
        Intent ii = new Intent(context, Workout.class);
        startActivity(ii);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean btnLogout(View view){
        Intent iii = new Intent(context, Tips.class);
        startActivity(iii);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JamesWierzba will this method work for multiple buttons on the same page and if so is there a chance you could show me how the syntax would look as I am a little bit confused. Many thanks you are a great help

Comment: Dude, you need `onClickListener`, please check your second [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547851/android-multiple-intents-one-form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a handler method for the onClick event:

```
<Button
...  
       android:onClick="handleClick()
..."/>
```

in code:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

...

public void handleClick(View view){
//do stuff
}

}
```

edit:

more concrete answer, given your code:

```
...
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnWorkout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnhealth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Log/View Workout" 
        android:onClick="btnWorkout"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnhealth"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Health Tips" 
        android:onClick="btnhealth"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnhealth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnhealth"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:onClick="btnLogout"/>
...
```

the attribute value of the android:onClick attribute is the name of the method that it will look for, in the corresponding java code for the activity...(keep in mind the signature of the method must the correct signature for a button click event handler, look at android docs for that ..)

I suggest you pick a different method name so that you don't get the id and the method name confused, as they are two separate references

Comment: will this method work for multiple buttons on the same page and if so is there a chance you could show me how the syntax would look as I am a little bit confused. Many thanks you are a great help